# Prioritized Replay Buffers and Annealing the Bias

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

In [prioritized replay buffers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.05952) we sample uniformly from k segments of the cumulative density function formed from a scaled version of the priority function below:

```
Priority(i) = sum(rank_i^alpha) / (rank_i^alpha)
```

rank_i is the rank of transition i in the priority buffer and alpha says how much prioritization to use.

The paper says that the prioritized replay introduces bias b/c it changes the original distribution in an uncontrolled fashion. The paper then says that the this problem is fixed by using weight importance sampling in our parameter updates. Our weights for importance sampling is as follows:

```
w_i = (1/N * 1/Priority(i))^beta
```

I do not see how this fixes the bias